# rsync multiple remote directories to local machine preserving directory paths

Tags: rsync

Would I be able to use rsync as such:

```
rsync -e ssh root@remote.com:/path/to/file:/path/to/second/file/ /local/directory/
```

or would i have to do something else?

Comment: The question's title ("remote directories") is different from the question's body ("remote files").

Comment: I was trying to preserve the directories as well just as much as the files.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Directly from the `rsync` man page:

```
The syntax for requesting multiple files from a remote host is done
by specifying additional remote-host args in the same style as the 
first, or with the hostname omitted.  For instance, all these work:

    rsync -av host:file1 :file2 host:file{3,4} /dest/
    rsync -av host::modname/file{1,2} host::modname/file3 /dest/
    rsync -av host::modname/file1 ::modname/file{3,4}
```

This means your example should have a space added before the second path:

```
rsync -e ssh root@remote.com:/path/to/file :/path/to/second/file/ /local/directory/
```

I'd suggest you first try it with the `-n` or `--dry-run` option, so you see what will be done, before the copy (and possible deletions) are actually performed.

Comment: I didn't think about this when I asked my question, but the dry run worked. Now, if I were to specify from multiple directories on my source, would I specify multiple destination directories as the same? Or is there a way to copy the whole folder and its contents to the destination? When I did the rsync command the first time, it just copied the contents of the file. In the man page it says something about --dirs or using -r. Or would it matter if I left the / on the end of the source file name?

Comment: If you want to copy directories, you just have to give the path to a directory as source.  If you're using `-r` (or `-a` as in the man page example), you'll then be copying the whole source directory into your destination, preserving the structure of this directory.

Comment: For posterity: this is apparently not true for old versions of rsync, such as the rsync 2.6.9 that seems to come with OSX 10.9; that version wants you to do `rsync -av host:'file1 file2'`, which gets awkward when filenames also have spaces in them. (Luckily, homebrew has a more recent version.)

Comment: I tried using a syntax like the `file{3,4}` curly bracket syntax on their example, and it didn't work.  It could be my non-bash shell though.

Comment: For even more post- posterity: rsync that comes built in with macOS 10.12 *still* uses the old syntax mentioned by @Dougal. Note that rsync 3 was released almost exactly 10 years before my comment here, whereas macOS uses the one released 12 years prior to this comment

Comment: And still more post-posterity: MacOS Catalina, 10.15.3 ***still*** ships with `rsync version 2.6.9`.

Answer (score 5):

just an actual example of @tonin. Download specific directories from live server

```
rsync -av root@123.124.137.147:/var/www/html/cls  \
:/var/www/html/index.php \
:/var/www/html/header.inc \
:/var/www/html/version.inc.php \
:/var/www/html/style.css \
:/var/www/html/accounts \
:/var/www/html/admin \
:/var/www/html/api \
:/var/www/html/config \
:/var/www/html/main \
:/var/www/html/reports .
```

Comment: I cannot seem to get that to work with special ssh port (as that requires a `-e`). Any idea?

Comment: @tcurdt add `-e 'ssh -p <port>'` to connect to a non-default ssh port